# C++ Differentiating Key Press vs Key Release

Tags: c++, key, release, curses, getch

I'm currently listening to keyboard inputs through a getch() while loop and everything is working great. However, if I'm holding left and press up, then the left movement is stopped until I press it again. The only way I can think of solving this requires knowing if a key is being held / when it is released. I'm using ncurses which supposedly has this ability, but through all my searches I haven't found anything useful.

Tetris Code Snippet in Question:

```
int ch = getch();
while(ch != 'x') {
   // Handle arrow keys first
   if (ch == '\033') {
      getch(); // Get rid of slash
      switch (getch()) {
         case 'A': rotate();    redraw(); break; // Up
         case 'B': move(DOWN);  redraw(); break; // Down
         case 'C': move(RIGHT); redraw(); break; // Right
         case 'D': move(LEFT);  redraw(); break; // Left
      }
   } else {
      switch(ch) {
        // Stuff not relevant to this question
      }
   }
   ch = getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more complicated than you think. It's called keyboard ghosting. To make sure multiple keys work when pressed simultaneously,you may need to have a specialized keyboard that provides anti-ghosting feature, or you may have to remap the Keyboard as per this article. [Read it here](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) for more detailed information.

Comment: are you sure he's facing this problem? i think he is asking about keyListener

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure, the problem is that the pressed key signals aren't reaching the hardware. I had a similar problem few days ago, I was working on SDL and I made an RPG game where I had to move my character in 8 directions. Top+left, top+right, bottom+left, bottom+right etc. Problem was that when the top key was pressed, and a left key was pressed later. The character stopped moving top. I made sure SDL_EnableKeyRepeat() was on and the problem still persisted. So I read about this article and changed the contorls. It works fine now. It's a hardware issue. Pretty understandable.

Comment: @OMerObaid, Also isn't keyListener a java thing? I thought this was a C++ question.

Comment: Anyone remember the game Star Control? That game shipped with a nice little tool called `keys` which allowed you to try out different key combinations to see which combinations could actually be registered simultaneously by a particular keyboard.